Best Practices for Automating Reporting in Salesforce Marketing Cloud
How can I automate reporting in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?
I write SQL queries to:

Track email recipients (e.g., reminders to complete an application).
Track how many hit the KPI (e.g., completed application) using data
in a DE.

Looking for best practices to streamline this process. Any suggestions?

Depends on what kind of reporting you are after. Are you looking for aggregates to send to managers in the morning? Also how many rows of data are we talking here? And how would you want the data to display?

You are asking a non-technical question, so you'll get a non-technical answer :)
Tracking data is fine, but you have almost zero infrastructure for custom reporting.
Short answer: export the raw data data to s3 or sftp, where another system that is built for reporting can pick it up.
Ask "Who needs what for what purpose": that determines the way forward. e.g. Managers want dashboards, Marketers want drilldowns. Whatever system can provide that to those users is where you set up reporting, based on the same tracking data you provide it via exports.
